# Solr7 and zookeeper behavior leading to deleted data directories, how to research/prevent

Tags: docker, solr, apache-zookeeper, ubuntu-18.04

During testing, I came across the following situation:

I had set up 3 VMs, all Ubuntu 18.04.

The first 2 machines had a solr7 instance. All 3 machines had a zookeeper. All of these are in Docker containers, the entire config deployed via Ansible.

Solr 7.5, Zookeeper 3.14.3

There's a frontend that acts as interface to insert stuff.

The zookeeper machines were set up to create an ensemble, which they properly did. They all had their id, a leader was elected, solr7 instances could connect and received their settings properly.

Inserting a bunch of data all worked fine.

Then I took down 2 of the VMs, leaving 1 with both a solr7 and zookeeper and redeployed the new config, without a zookeeper ensemble.

This did not work, the interface refused to come up, it all took too long so I decided to go back to 3 VMs.

While I could once again connect, I noticed all data was gone.

Even worse, when looking at the location of the solr data directories, those were all gone. Every single collection/core was gone.

I've been trying to google this issue, but there seems to be no documentation of anything like this.

My current working theory is that solr started and asked the zookeeper ensemble for its configuration. Zookeeper either was not in sync or lost its settings and sent an empty reply or did not reply at all. To which solr decided to remove the existing data folders, as the received config specified nothing/not receiving a config at all.

That's just guesswork though. I'm at a complete loss even finding information about this

I'm not even sure what to search for. All results I get are "how to delete solr cores" or "how to remove collections".

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.

EDIT: After talking about it on the solr mailing list, a ticket was made for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-13396

Comment: Shot in the dark: I has something vaguely similar happen to me once and it was because I was starting the docker image from scratch and not continuing from the container with the data.

Comment: .. and be aware that your containers may not persist data in any way, except when using volumes or bind mounts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried again recently and could not replicate. That is to say: nothing crashed and all data was still present. A strange case indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking about it on the solr mailing list, a bug ticket was made: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-13396

So answering my own question so this can be closed.